# Как удалить bitmap из ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, массивы

Я использую функцию `remove()`, в таком контексте:

```
Singelton.getInstanse().getArrayBitmap().get(position).remove();
```

Но метод `remove()` не распознается.
Какой метод нужно применить, чтобы удалить объект из ячейки массива?

Comment: Метод remove в ArrayList реализован в двух видах. Туда нужно [передавать либо индекс элемента](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) (удалит элемент на указанном месте), [либо объект](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) (удалит найденный объект с наименьшим индексом)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод ```remove``` у самого объекта ```Bitmap```, которого у него нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Singelton.getInstanse().getArrayBitmap().remove(position);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmArrayList = Singelton.getInstanse().getArrayBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap = Singelton.getInstanse().getArrayBitmap().get(position);
bmArrayList.remove(bitmap);
```

Так попробуйте

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте метод внутри Singletone написать

```
    public final class Singleton {

        private static ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray;

        /** Single ton constructor. */
        private Singleton() {
        }

        public static void removeByPosition(int position) {
            bitmapArray.remove(position);
        }

    }
```